# UWP: EmailMessage uses comma instead of semicolon

Tags: c#, uwp, mailmessage

I want to create a new mail in the default mail app using UWP. Therefore I've written the following code:

```
    List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        emailAddresses = new List<string>();
        emailAddresses.Add("xx1@yyy.zzz");
        emailAddresses.Add("xx2@yyy.zzz");

        await ComposeEmail();
    }

    async Task ComposeEmail()
    {
        var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();

        foreach (string mailadress in emailAddresses)
        {
            var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(mailadress);
            emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
        }

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
    }
```

But the recipients in the mail which is created by this code are comma separated. If I try to send this mail with MS Outlook I'll get the message that I have to insert the recepients semicolon separated.
But I don't find a way to change this. I've also searched with Google - but I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you in forward.

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: What happens if you add a name in the second parameter of the `EmailRecipient` constructor?

Comment: You could simply open a mailto: URI if you dont find any other solution.

Comment: Maybe check your regional setting : Control Panel -> Region - Additional Setting and check the list seperator value. try to change that and see if that works

Comment: I reproduced this issue and reported to related team. currently, there is a work around that set the default mail app as uwp mail app. this issue does not happened in uwp mail app.

Comment: We’re aware of this issue and the Outlook team will investigate the issue. If there is any updates I will comment below.